# splitting csv in pandas series python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe like this:

```
df = userid        accessto
    432        pc,internet,wifi
    233        pc
    235        wifi,laptoop,mobile
    236        wifi,laptoop,mobile,pc
```

and I want it like this:

```
userid      device
432          pc
432          internet
432          wifi
233          pc
235          wifi
235          laptop
235          mobile
```

So far what I have done is like this:

```
import pandas as pd 
s = df.accessto
s = s.str.split(',', expand = True) 
s
```

How do I get the 's' back with the original df?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
s = (df.pop('accessto').str.split(',', expand = True)
       .stack()
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
       .rename('device'))
print (s)
0          pc
0    internet
0        wifi
1          pc
2        wifi
2     laptoop
2      mobile
3        wifi
3     laptoop
3      mobile
3          pc
Name: device, dtype: object

df = df.join(s).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    userid    device
0      432        pc
1      432  internet
2      432      wifi
3      233        pc
4      235      wifi
5      235   laptoop
6      235    mobile
7      236      wifi
8      236   laptoop
9      236    mobile
10     236        pc
```

**Explanation**:

1. First [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) column for extract with [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) column with `expand = True` to `DataFrame`
2. Reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
3. [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for remove first level of `MultiIndex`
4. `rename` `Series` by new column name
5. Last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original df

Or:

```
from itertools import chain

s = df['accessto'].str.split(',')
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'userid' : df['userid'].repeat(s.str.len()).values,
    'accessto' : list(chain.from_iterable(s.values))
})

print (df)
    userid  accessto
0      432        pc
1      432  internet
2      432      wifi
3      233        pc
4      235      wifi
5      235   laptoop
6      235    mobile
7      236      wifi
8      236   laptoop
9      236    mobile
10     236        pc
```